# Getting a modal on an input tag

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I'm developing a requisition system and I have an input tag in php that I want to put a modal. How can that be made possible? I've tried following the syntax used in html but it is not working on the form that I want the modal to be in.

```
<input  class='edit' 
                                      name='edit' 
                                      type='submit' 
                                      value='EDIT' 
                                      data-target='#myModal'
                                      data-toggle='modal'


                               />

<!--==============================MODAL==============================-->
```

×
          EDIT PAGE
        
        

           0) {
                            echo "
                                      ITEM
                                      DESCRIPTION
                                      QUANTITY
                                      EDIT
                                        ";
                       // output data of each row
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                              echo "
                                  " . $row["Item"]. " 
                                  ". $row["Description"]. " 
                                  " . $row["Quantity"]. "

                                  ";
                                 }
                              echo "";
                          } else {
                           echo "0 RESULTS";
                            }

                $conn->close();
?>


        

        
          Close

Comment: Post Your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried giving type='button' in tag